# MSIL to Native code stored

Tags: c#, jit

Its very basic question.

JIT compilation is on demand as per MSDN [MSIL To Native Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
Every time when we run the assembly JIT compiler converts MSIL to Native language? Or When we run assembly first time, it converts and store the native language code to somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JIT compiler compiles your code when you start the application and stores it in *memory*.

This code *can* be cached by [`ngen.exe` (Native Image Generator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and stored in the *native image cache*. This will be automatically loaded the next time you start the application, and you won't have to JIT the MSIL code a second time.

> Ngen.exe creates native images, which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer. The runtime can use native images from the cache instead of using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly.

The native image cache can be found on a path similar to `C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64`. This path is not accessible through Windows Explorer, so use `cmd` or a powershell.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does that mean each time we run the assembly MSIL is converted to Native code by JIT? because of which  application would take long time to start.

Comment: Well, GAC isn't the same as "native image cache"

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'm not 100% sure, but I think the native image cache is either part of the GAC, or they work together. Through a command line tool, you can reach the GAC on `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC` and the native image cache on `C:\Windows\assembly\Native...`. But, if you go to `C:\Windows\assembly` through the windows Explorer, a shell extension will show you the contents of both.

Comment: @dcastro BTW if I'm not wrong, shell extension is deprecated, who knows if it reflects the actual state of GAC and image cache...

Comment: @user2323308 No, it means the opposite. The first time you run the assembly, IL is compiled into native code. NGEN will cache the native code, so it can be reused the next time you run the application.